# About mod_rewrite htaccess clean URL parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

My URL: `www.example.com/index.php?fruit=banana&color=yellow&amount=2`

It should be:
`www.example.com/banana/yellow/2`     -----> success

So why is it:
`www.example.com/banana/2`     -----> ERROR

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ ./index.php?fruit=$1&color=$2&amount=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I don't see a rule matching `/banana/2` so it's not surprising that doesn't work

Comment: your rule simply takes 3 parameters and you're passing only 2 .. that's the problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer...how to get work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ./index.php?fruit=$1&color=$2&amount=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ./index.php?fruit=$1&amount=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```